What possibilities do I have for publishing a disputed manuscript?
There is an unpublished research paper that I partly wrote while working as a postdoc at my former institute. Part of the work was done at my current institute where I am an assistant professor. Dispute arose with the supervisor of the postdoc project as whether I could use my current institute's affiliation (as the second affiliation) for this paper. Later it was revealed that it was possible and he had been trying to mislead me, because me not using another affiliation would incur extra research points for him. My complaint to the former institute was not of any avail. After a while we were able to make a compromise to include my new affiliation as well, however dispute arose again regarding the contribution statement.
I am not able to continue any form of collaboration or even contact with this person because of his attitude; and I want to publish my paper too. The contract with the former institute states that results of the research is not allowed to be published without coordination with the supervisor and he has to be the corresponding author. On the other hand, major publishers state that a significant contribution is needed for a person to be considered an author. The supervisor's contribution was to read the paper and offer some comments, mostly on grammar and punctuation.
I can take a version of the manuscript before it was sent to him (which is not much different from the current one) and submit it alone. But he can make a complaint to our higher education ministry and cite the fact that the manuscript has been submitted a few times with him as an author.  (Before I became aware of the whole affiliation and research points business, the paper was submitted twice and rejected.)  It is worth mentioning that the first submission of the paper was done after me joining my current institute and that all the aspects of the work such as methodology, data analysis, visualization and writing of the manuscript was done before the supervisor even saw the paper.
Now the question: what is that I can do for publishing this paper?

There are at least two different possible questions in here: 1) Can you publish this paper without violating publishing ethics (and how)? 2) How to handle any problems arising from breaking your contract (which violates academic publishing ethics)? The latter question is primarily about the pertinent jurisdiction’s contract laws on which we are not experts, even if you name the jurisdiction. We may answer the former question (or a similar one), but please [edit] your question to specify what exactly you want to achieve and roughly what risks you are willing to take.

As a sidenote: I see the fact that a contract compelled you to make your supervisor co-author as a good explanation why he was co-author in previous submissions.

You have obviously accepted a bad contract. I don't know why you did it in the first place, but now it prevails. So, publish as required by the contract (with the supervisor as a corresponding co-author). As to the "contribution statement", if that is the only remaining obstacle, just accept the supervisor demands, put the whole story behind you, and never get engaged into a collaboration with that person again. What you are both doing now is just to harm the general reputation of the scientist profession in the eyes of the general public.

@fedja: That should be an answer, although I would wait from clarification from the author. As for honouring the contract: It may also be unenforceable through clashing with academic norms, (but that’s not a question we can answer here).

@Wrzlprmft - contract law clashing with academic norms is better suited to Law SE, but I really doubt that a judge would look beyond the letter of the law.

What is wrong with listing the old place as your address, the new place as your current address?  Happens all the time.

Why not submit to a journal without a contribution statement?

What is this research points business?  Is this in the UK?

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but I will offer another option.
Walk away from this. This is a paper that has been rejected twice already. There is obvious "baggage" and potential negative outcome from pursuing this. You are an assistant professor, your focus should be on establishing your independent career, so a mediocre paper with your prior advisor (regardless of your current independent affiliation) does not do much to help you.
So just let it go and focus your energy on new independent work solely from you. This will have much more value. I realize this idea hurts as you are walking away from something you rightfully feel is yours, but in the grand scheme of things it is a sunk cost and not worthy of you throwing anything more at it.

The affiliations for each author should include every affiliation the authors have or had from the time the research started until the time the paper is accepted.  Order doesn't really matter, but my pref is current affiliation first.
If this doesn't make it perfectly clear where the research was done, then be specific about it in the acknowledgement section, or any other section where this info is usually included for a given journal.  The line could read something like "This work was supported by NIH AB12345-03 to Dr. Frankenstein, University of Transylvania"
